# Definition of $H_\lambda$ (hereditary cardinality)

Tags: set-theory, definition

It seems to me that the definition of $H_\lambda$ (the set of sets of hereditary cardinality less than $\lambda$) on the web page at [Cantor's Attic](http://cantorsattic.info/Hereditary_Cardinality#Definition_and_Basic_Absoluteness_Properties) is not quite correct. From the page:

> $H_\lambda=\{x: |\operatorname{trcl}(x)|<\lambda\}$ where $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ denotes the transitive closure of $x$.

This is correct when $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal, but if $\lambda$ is singular then the definition should include any cofinal subset of $\lambda$ with size less than $\lambda$, which this definition doesn't.  Indeed, if $\lambda$ is a singular cardinal, $A \subset \lambda$ is cofinal, and $|A| < \lambda$, then because $A$, its elements, their elements, and so on all have cardinality less than $\lambda$ then we should say that $A$ has hereditary cardinality less than $\lambda$ if we want the terminology to make any sense.

I think the closest definition of $H_\lambda$ that would be correct is

> $H_\lambda=\{x: \forall y \in \operatorname{trcl}(\{x\})\, (|y| <\lambda)\}$.

My question for Math.SE is whether I'm correct that there is a mistake, and if so, what the best definition would be (so that I can fix the page.)  In my experience $H_\lambda$ is only ever used when $\lambda$ is regular, so the existing definition could be fixed by restricting it to this case, which is what Jech does in the exercises to Chapter 12.  On the other hand, the second definition proposed above has the feature that it generalizes better to the case of "hereditarily in $P$" where $P$ is some class other than $\{y : |y| < \lambda\}$, I think.  There might be a third definition that is even better.  What is standard?  What is best?

Comment: I really  don't see what may fail, $H_\lambda\subset V_\lambda$ holds by induction. Also, Kunen defines $H_\lambda$ as in your link for all infinite cardinals.

Comment: @azarel What is the proof of the limit step when $\lambda$ is singular?  (Also, what about my counterexample?)

Comment: @azarel I should clarify:  I was only claiming that $H_\lambda \subset V_\lambda$ can fail with the second definition (not the one from the link.)  This claim is potentially confusing, so I'm removing it from the question.

Comment: This may be of interest too: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81815/is-the-axiom-of-union-independent-of-the-rest-of-zf (Perhaps, you we're already of aware of this though!)

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, that is interesting.  Maybe I can incorporate it into our class in the next few weeks.

Comment: That would be cool, I actually thought you might have had that in mind, when you defined it like that.

Comment: @Ryan I wish I always thought that far ahead.  I only defined it like that because to me it was the obvious formulation of the intuitive concept.  It did have the nice side effect of tripping up some students on the homework, which is how this Math.SE question came about :-)

Comment: @TrevorWilson Haha ok, I see! I had never seen it like that until I read that question a few weeks back, and then you defined it like that and I was like oh! I think it is the more intuitive idea, but it seems like that definition is harder to work with.

Comment: I know that you find this to be elementary, but I think that by the standards of this site it's not. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct. For the reasons you discuss, the appropriate definition of $H_\lambda$ for singular $\lambda$ is the set of $x$ such that $x$ and all sets in its transitive closure have size below $\lambda$. (Though I could not instantly find a reference, this is actually standard among those that consider the set at all, which are not too many, and its use is somewhat limited. For example, I would imagine one may want to consider the class in settings where choice fails, but I have yet to see an application in that context.)

On the other hand, it is also standard (and far more common) to only define $H_\lambda$ for $\lambda$ regular.

---

Mostly as a curiosity: Some people (Forster, for example), present $H_\kappa$ as $\bigcap\{y\mid \mathcal P_\kappa(y)\subseteq y\}$. This presentation generalizes: We can define $$\mathcal P_\phi(x)=\{y\subseteq x\mid \phi(y)\},$$ so $\mathcal P_\kappa(x)$ is $\mathcal P_{|y|<\kappa}(x)$. One can then define $H_\phi$ as $\bigcap\{y\mid\mathcal P_\phi(y)\subseteq y\}$. This notation seems to go back to

> Maurice Boffa. *Sur l'ensemble des ensembles héréditairement de puissance inférieure à un cardinal infini donné*, Bull. Soc. Math. Belg., **22**, (1970), 115–118. [MR0309732 (46 #8837)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=309732).

Note this version coincides with the standard one for $\kappa$ regular, but is the problematic one for $\kappa$ singular.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I like the definition as "the smallest set such that..." although I suppose it hides the complexity of proving that there is such a set.  When you say "this version...is the problematic one for $\kappa$ singular" do you mean it coincides with the one that I thought was problematic?

Comment: Hi Trevor. Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 7):

Although the definition that Trevor quoted from Cantor's Attic fails, as he says, to match the usual meaning of "hereditarily", it is, as far as I know, fairly standard.  I suspect the reason (or at least a reason) for that is that it works well in Lévy's cardinal boundedness theorem: Anything $\Delta_1$-definable from sets in $H_\lambda$ is itself in $H_\lambda$.  If you change the definition so that a small cofinal subset $A$ of a singular $\lambda$ becomes an element of $H_\lambda$, then this theorem fails, because $\lambda$ itself is $\Delta_1$-definable from $A$ as the union of $A$.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't heard of that theorem before.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Lévy's theorem is a nice way to isolate the condensation argument used in the proof of GCH in $L$. If $X$ is a constructible subset of an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, then the first ordinal $\alpha$ with $X\in L_\alpha$ is $\Delta^1$-definable from $X$. So, since $X\in H_{\kappa^+}$, Lévy gives $\alpha\in H_{\kappa^+}$, which means $\alpha<\kappa^+$. Lévy's theorem also gives a convenient way to prove that, for example, the power set operation is not $\Delta^1$-definable.

Comment: I see, that is nice.  It will be very useful to me in a week or two when I teach these things for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

In [On the Transitive Hull of a $\kappa$-narrow Relation](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.19920380137) and [On $\kappa$-hereditary Sets and Consequences of the Axiom of Choice](https://doi.org/10.1002/1521-3870(200010)46:4%3C563::AID-MALQ563%3E3.0.CO;2-6), Karl-Heinz Diener defines:

> The Strict Hereditary Set of Cardinality $<κ$

as: $$H_κ=\{x∈{\bf WF}\mid|\mbox{trcl}(x)|<κ\}$$
and defines:

> The Hereditary Set of Cardinality $<κ$

as: $$HC_κ=\{x∈{\bf WF}\mid y\in\mbox{trcl}(\{x\})⇒|y|<κ\}$$

And the $HC_κ$ definition is exactly what you suggested.

Comment: With David Asperó we have a paper about proper forcing in ZF, and we give a "better" definition of $H_\kappa$ in the absence of choice, specifically, one that reflects the failure of AC in the universe and coincides with the standard one when ZFC holds.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Which paper is that?

Comment: @Ari: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04077