# Is the class of all finite graphs a set or a proper class in ZF?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, axioms

A graph is an adjacency relation among vertices. So, I think each finite graph is a set by subset axiom schema. Is the collection of all finite graphs too large to be a set in ZF?

Comment: It is a proper class. Already the graphs of size one form a proper class. Of course, each individual finite graph is a set.

Comment: As I point out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3471215/462), any collection of structures that contains a nonempty set and is closed under isomorphism is a proper class.

Comment: However you can get them into a set by demanding that all vertices of the finite graph are hereditary finite sets (let's call such graphs hereditary finite graphs). Then a hereditary finite graph itself is also a hereditary finite set, and the hereditary finite sets form a set. Note that every finite graph is isomorphic to a hereditary finite one.

Comment: Why do you think that moving from ZFC to ZF is going to change anything? *Especially* when you're talking about finite graphs?

Comment: @Asaf, Axiom of choice is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Normally, when you move from ZFC to ZF, you are trying to indicate that the axiom of choice *is* relevant. Not always, but that's the standard reading.

Comment: @Asaf, Thanks for pointing this out. The edit simply reflects that I should have written ZF instead of ZFC when I first raised the question.