# About the definition of hereditary cardinality

Tags: logic, set-theory, definition, cardinals, ordinals

I've seen these two definitions of sets that are hereditarily of cardinality $< \kappa$.

1. $x$ is hereditarily of cardinality $< \kappa$ iff $|trcl(x)| < \kappa$
2. $x$ is hereditarily of cardinality $< \kappa$ iff $|x| < \kappa $, and for all $y\in trcl(x)$, $|y| < \kappa$

According to [this article](http://cantorsattic.info/Hereditary_Cardinality#Definition_and_Basic_Absoluteness_Properties) (and also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/575503/1037257)), the two definitions agree when $\kappa$ is regular and don't agree when it is singular. I'm not very fluent with regular/singular cardinals, and the author of the cited answer said he couldn't find a reference that discusses these two definitions. Could anyone explain (in detail, if possible) why the above definitions are equivalent for regular cardinals and what goes wrong for singular ones? (I know that the cited question partially answers my second question ("the definition should include any cofinal subset of $\kappa$ with size less than $\kappa$" ), but I'd appreciate more details.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one key point here is that $\kappa$ is a regular if and only if whenever $\lambda<\kappa$, and $\{A_i\mid i<\lambda\}$ is such that $|A_i|<\kappa$, then $|\bigcup\{A_i\mid i<\lambda\}|<\kappa$.

Now, if $\kappa$ is regular, note that $\operatorname{trcl}(x)=x\cup\bigcup x\cup\bigcup\bigcup x\cup\bigcup\bigcup\bigcup x\cup\dots$. If $|x|<\kappa$, and each $y\in x$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$, then $\bigcup x$ has size less than $\kappa$; inductively, the whole union, which is $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$, has size less than $\kappa$ (note that if $\kappa=\omega$, then these iterated $\bigcup$ operations must stabilise after a finite number of steps, too).

In the other direction, if $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ is smaller than $\kappa$, then by the virtue of transitivity, whenever $y\in\operatorname{trcl}(x)$, it must also be a subset of $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$, as would $x$ itself be, so the 2nd definition must hold as well.

---

Now, if $\kappa$ is singular, there is some $\lambda<\kappa$ and $A_i$ for $i<\lambda$ such that $|A_i|<\kappa$, but $\bigcup A_i=\kappa$. For example, in the case of $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$, simply take $\lambda=\omega$ and $A_i=\aleph_i$.

But now the set $x=\{A_i\mid i<\lambda\}$ has size $\lambda<\kappa$; each of its elements is a subset of $\kappa$ of size $<\kappa$, and $\operatorname{trcl}(x)=\kappa\cup x$, so easily all of the elements there have size $<\kappa$ as well. But, alas, $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ has size $\kappa$.

Comment: How is the regularity of $\kappa$ used in the characterization of $trcl(x)$ that you have in the second paragraph? I thought a general definition of transitive closure is that $trcl_x(0)=x, trcl_x(n+1)=\bigcup trcl_x(n), trcl(x)=\cup_{n} trcl_x(n)$; does it not work for singular cardinals? And a possibly related question -- I don't see how you found $trcl(x)=\kappa \cup x$ in the last paragraph.

Comment: It's not used in the characterisation. It is used to show that each set, $x$ and $\bigcup x$ and so on, have size $<\kappa$, and therefore $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ has size less than $\kappa$ as well. As for "the general definition", yes, that is ***exactly*** what I wrote there. You can also define it as the intersection of all transitive sets which contain $x$.

Comment: Oh, I interpreted the beginning of the second paragraph as "if $\kappa$ is regular, then $trcl(x)=...$ (what you have)", but now I see that the regularity of $\kappa$ doesn't have anything to do with the definition of trcl. In the next sentence, when you say "each $y\in x$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$", did you mean to say "each $y\in trcl(x)$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$"? (Because I think you wanted to assume what the second definition is saying.)

Comment: That is a consequence, since $x\subseteq\operatorname{trcl}(x)$.

Comment: So you're assuming less than the second definition is saying (and then the second definition can be made stronger by weakening the assumption $\forall y\in trcl(x), |y| < \kappa$ to  $\forall y\in x, |y| < \kappa$)? Also, I'm still not very clear on how the $A_i$s from the characterization of regularity play a role in showing that $\bigcup x$ has size less than $\kappa$, but maybe I should  move this to a separate question...

Comment: No. I am not weakening any assumptions. I am using $y\in x$ *as a first step* to argue that $\bigcup x$ has size $<\kappa$. Next, $y\in\bigcup x$, and the previous conclusion combine to $\bigcup\bigcup x$ being $<\kappa$. Next, proceed by induction. Then argue that a countable union of sets of size $<\kappa$ is again of size $<\kappa$ (because, again, $\kappa$ is regular).

Comment: For the last point ("a countable union of sets of size $< \kappa$ has size $< \kappa$"), do we just apply your characterization of regular cardinals to $\lambda=\omega$ and $A_i=\bigcup^i x$? But if so, this only works for $\kappa$ such that $\omega < \kappa$.

Comment: Well, if you continue reading the answer, you'll find out what happens when $\kappa=\omega$...

Comment: What do you mean by stabilise after a finite number of steps? The case $\kappa = \omega$ is confusing -- I believe what needs to be proved is that the countable union of finite sets is finite (each $\cup^i x$ is finite, and we need to prove that $\cup_{i < \omega} \cup^i x$ is finite), but isn't that false?